# Android Google plus how to NOT share my location

Tags: android, share, google-plus

Here is the thing, when you are sharing using android Google plus this what it does:

For your first attempt to share anything, you will get 5 steps process when you be asked to think all what you got(including your sole) with Google plus app.

Then you will be finally redirected to the share activity, witch at first starting by 5 sec of loading in order to attach your current location to the post.

Lets ignore for a sec about the first(unforgettable) time. But for all the rest of times when I wish to share some thing from my app, how can I do this **WITHOUT** attaching my users location?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. When you broadcast an Intent to share something (like text) and the user selects an app to complete the action, it's completely out of your control. There are (thankfully) no flags you can set to disallow things like attaching location on the other end of the Intent.

Think about the implications of allowing the sender of an intent to dictate how the reciever handles it. You can't predict how the user will want to share something. If they don't want to share location, they'll remove it. If they do want to share location, you shouldn't be able to block them. If they don't like how slow Google Plus is, they won't use it.

This isn't your problem and trying to make it yours will only frustrate users.

Comment: may be it is their decision if add or not add a location. But those are my 5 sec!